# TabHost and include

Tags: android, include, android-tabhost

I am new to android.
I  would like to have a tabhost with includes but tabs won't show.
This 2 includes have simple or basic inputs logic like textbox and buttons.
All the codes is within this main activity, like saving db stuff and others.

Here is the code.

```html
    <TabHost
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/tabHost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/line"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"></TabWidget>
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <include android:id="@+id/layout1"
                    layout="@layout/layout_add_details"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"></include>
                <include android:id="@+id/layout2"
                    layout="@layout/layout_add_number"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"></include>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
```

Here is how I setup the tabhost.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        TabHost tab = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
        tab.setup();

        TabHost.TabSpec spec1 = tab.newTabSpec("TAB 1");
        spec1.setIndicator("TAB 1");
        spec1.setContent(R.id.layout1);
        tab.addTab(spec1);

        TabHost.TabSpec spec2 = tab.newTabSpec("TAB 2");
        spec2.setIndicator("TAB 2");
        spec2.setContent(R.id.layout2);
        tab.addTab(spec2);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

thiis is how I solved mine. I have a Tabhost with three tabs inside. On the second one I have Google's Map Fragment and on the other two I have simple text boxes. **Only the third Tab** is added using the **include** setting

So this is how the main layout looks like

```
    <TabHost
        android:id="@+id/tab_host_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="tab one"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/map_tab"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <fragment
                        android:id="@+id/map"
                        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        tools:context=".MapsActivity" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <include
                        layout="@layout/tab_three_content"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


                </FrameLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
```

And this is the tab three layout that I created separately and inserted in the previous layout using the include.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello from tab three"/>

</LinearLayout>
```